# Training and validation accuracy extremely low for Autonomous Lane Navigation via Deep Learning

Tags: deep-learning, machine-learning-model, convolutional-neural-network

Using a SmartCar running on RPI4 i collected all the images necessary for training. Training is done using CNN Nvidia's Model with Tensorflow and Python.
Took about 900 Images for Up and 800sh for the down run. See sample Image here:

[image]

The steering log files were also generated with the pictures between -1 and 1 and both saved to Lists.

The data was then balanced using samples per Bin to throw away extra images which are only going straight.

The following two images before and after balancing the data:

[image: Before Blancing]

[image]

In the next step I split the data for Training and Validation:

```
xTrain, xVal, yTrain, yVal = train_test_split(imagesPath, steering, test_size=0.2, random_state=5)
print('Total Training Images: ',len(xTrain))
print('Total Validation Images: ',len(xVal))
```

After using random Augmentation and Preprocessing the Images the following model is created:

```
 def createModel():
  model = Sequential()

  model.add(Convolution2D(24, (5, 5), (2, 2), input_shape=(66, 200, 3), activation='elu'))
  model.add(Convolution2D(36, (5, 5), (2, 2), activation='elu'))
  model.add(Convolution2D(48, (5, 5), (2, 2), activation='elu'))
  model.add(Convolution2D(64, (3, 3), activation='elu'))
  #model.add(Dropout(0.2)) #extra for stability
  model.add(Convolution2D(64, (3, 3), activation='elu'))
  #connected fully Layers
  model.add(Flatten())
  #model.add(Dropout(0.2))
  model.add(Dense(100, activation = 'elu'))
  model.add(Dense(50, activation = 'elu'))
  model.add(Dense(10, activation = 'elu'))
  #output layer
  model.add(Dense(1))

  model.compile(Adam(lr=0.0001),loss='mse',metrics=['accuracy'])
  return model

model = createModel()
```

And lastly the Training:

```
checkpoint_callback = tensorflow.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint('model.h5', verbose=1, save_best_only=True)
    
history = model.fit_generator(dataGen(xTrain, yTrain, 100, 1),
                                      steps_per_epoch=300,
                                      epochs=10,
                                      validation_data=dataGen(xVal, yVal, 100, 0),
                                      validation_steps=200,
                                      verbose=1,
                                      shuffle=1,
                                      callbacks=[checkpoint_callback])
```

Somehow the Training Accuracy and the Validation accuracy are really low at about 50%.
The Augmentation and Preprocessing is done according to Nvidia.

The steps I took to solve the issue:

1. Decrease the Number of images from 5000 up to 700 which increased the Train and Validation accuracy to about 69% but even after training for 30 epochs it only improved very slightly.
2. Changed the samples per Bin of data threshold from 300 to 600. This somehow increased the accuracy but the other steering angles were negligible and only going straight 0 was dominant.
3. The resulting Mean Squared Error was 0.098 and $R^2$ value was 73.52% max after all the tweaking.

Any suggestions on how to increase the Training and Validation accuracy would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: What is the value that you're trying your model to predict? The output layer of the model has only one node whereas your visualization shows multiple bins ranging from -0.6 to 0.6. The fact that lowering the number of images used increases accuracy might indicate that the network you are using does not have enough capacity to learn, so you might try increasing the size of your network.

Comment: The model should look at an image and predict the steering angle in this case from -0.6 to 0.6 as there aren’t many sharp turns here. Later using the camera mounted on the car it would track the lane. I’m relatively new to Deep learning so if you have more knowledge about “increasing the size” of the network would be cool. I’m using the Model used by NVIDIA and many others online. So I fail to understand the results.

Comment: Are the values from -0.6 to 0.6 continuous or categorical? Based on the type of loss you are using you are performing a regression task, it therefore doesn't make sense to look at accuracy since that is only applicable to classification tasks. When it comes to increase the size of the network you can try increasing the number of filters/nodes in the existing layers, or adding extra layers to the network.

Comment: Ok I think your first point actually makes sense. I never thought of that. So only Validation loss is of interest to me right? Also thank you.

Comment: It’s just one value for one image. So in that case the Accuracy isn’t needed but can you elaborate a bit more in easy terms.

Comment: Accuracy doesn't make sense when you are performing regression. For example, what would the accuracy be in the case that the value should be -0.3 but your model is predicting -0.2995? The value is not exactly the same (and likely will never be) so looking at the accuracy doesn't really inform you on well the model is predicting values.